# Searching data using regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I want to search in my data. I'm using regular expression with IsMatch() function.

I have a class:

```
public  class MyClass
    {
        public  string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to search in my data by Name Or Address, and Name or Address Like input
With input FuzzySearch is: `a%b` or `a%b%c` or japanese characters (ex:`区%水`).

In main function I have a list: `List<MyClass> data` and using regular expression with IsMatch() function as below:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(FuzzySearch, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);


var allInfoList1 = allInfoList.Where(x => regex.IsMatch(x.Name) ||
                                      regex.IsMatch(x.Address)).ToList();
```

Sometime result is true, but sometime result is wrong( with case input is japanese characters)

(Is the regular expression not support unicode?)
Are there any other solutions?

Comment: The regex `a%b` only matches a string that contains `"a%b"` literally; can you please post what you're actually using as "fuzzy search" regexes?

Comment: Both .Net and the .Net regex engine work with Unicode. In fact, as far as I know, that's the only way they can work - though I suppose `RegexOptions.CultureInvariant` can make a difference.

Comment: @ Tim Pietzcker : with case FruzzySearch is a%b, result is true, but with case FruzzySearch is 北道%幌市%石%菊%五条 rusult is wrong. My actually is my regex work as Like in SQL

Answer (score 1):

Rather than implementing your own document search engine, I would suggest considering tools like [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) or [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/). I do not know your specific use case, and perhaps my suggestion is an overkill, but I would give it a thought.

Hope I helped!

Comment: Thanks you, But i use it in linq and .net.:(